# Normalisation in fractional integration and Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, fractional-calculus

Fractional Brownian motion comes in two forms (following Marinucci and Robinson 1998) for fraction $\alpha$ and Brownian motion $W_s$:

**Type II** (Levy, Volterra, Riemann)
$$ \tilde W^\alpha_t = \int_0^t (t-s)^\alpha \; dW_s $$
**Type I** (Mandelbrot-Van Ness, Liouville)
$$ W^\alpha_t = \int_{-\infty}^t (t-s)^\alpha + (-s)^\alpha_+ \; dW_s $$

I would like to understand the "normalisation term" $\int_{-\infty}^0 (-s)^\alpha \; dW_s $, without which (and changing the lower bound $0\to-\infty$) the two definitions would coincide.

---

Can fractional calculus be used to make the difference clearer? Recall that fractional integration (with basepoint $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and fraction $\alpha$) is usually defined as the Riemann-Liouville operator 
$$ \tilde I^\alpha_a[f](t) = \int_a^t f(s)(t-s)^{\alpha-1} \; ds. $$

Allowing for the replacement of normal integration ($ds$) by stochastic integration ($dW_s$), we see $\tilde W^\alpha_t = \tilde I_0^{\alpha+1}[1] = \tilde I_0^\alpha[W_t]$, i.e. the fractional integral of normal Brownian motion. (We choose $a=0$ by convention, but the result is the same for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ up to change of variable.)

Following [arXiv:0912.3168](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3168), Section 2.2.2, one can define

$$ I^\alpha[f](t) = \tilde I_{-\infty}^\alpha[f](t)-\tilde I_{-\infty}^\alpha[f](0) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(s)\cdot((t-s)^\alpha-(-s)_+^\alpha) \; ds. $$

It follows that $W^\alpha_t = I^{\alpha+1}[1] = I^\alpha[W_t] = {}_{-\infty}\tilde I_\alpha[W_t]-{}_{-\infty}\tilde I_\alpha[W_0]$, so we can see both types of fBm as a result of (different) fractional integrals of ordinary Brownian motion.

---

My questions:

1. Where does the normalisation term come from?
2. Is there a terminology/theory for these changes from finite to infinite basepoints?
3. How can the definition of $I^\alpha[\cdot]$ from $\tilde I_a^\alpha[\cdot]$ be motivated: why is the formal replacement $a\to-\infty$ not enough, in what way is $-\tilde I_{-\infty}^\alpha[f](0)$ necessary?  Is there a characterisation, a functor, ... ? What extra properties does $I^\alpha[f](t)$ have compared to $\tilde I_a^\alpha[f](t)$ ?
4. Given an arbitrary kernel $k(t)$ yielding a $k(t)$-Brownian motion ${}_a\hat W^k_t = \int^t_a k(t-s) \; dW_s$, is ${}_{-\infty}\hat W^k_t-{}_{-\infty}\hat W^k_0$ always an appropriate "normalisation" and what properties does it gain?

My particular interest is in fractional Brownian motions (e.g. because type I has a nicer covariance structure than type II), but my aim is to understand the construction/difference in a general way. Apologies if this tension makes the questions less clear.

Comment: I think the main reason to consider "Type I" definition is to get a process that is stationary in time: $Y_t = X_{t_0+t} - X_{t_0}$ is to have equal law as the original process $X_t$. In "Type II" definition this is not the case. However, "Type I" definition can be obtained as the limit as $t_0 \to \infty$ of the law of $Y_t$ if $X_t$ has "Type II" law.